# MSE gains a tag through migration, tag lives on

Tags: support, migration, tag-management

A few weeks ago, [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29251/bit-error-probability-for-8psk) was asked on MSE and [migrated](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1683906/revisions) to another SE site. During that process, an MSE tag, [coding-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory), was removed and a DSP tag, [digital-communications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-communications), was added.

But the tag [digital-communications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-communications) is still showing up in the [newly created tag list](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) at the time of writing.

Will it eventually be removed from the MSE tag system? I wanted to ask the question a few days after the migration, but tried to give it some time to see if the more frequent automatic tag clean-up process did anything. I assume that process has now happened once or twice since migration, but perhaps not.

The odd thing is that if you hover over the tag on that newly created tag list, it still shows one question (the migrated one), even though that question lives on another site now.

Sidenote: I'm very hesitant to tag this post as a bug, but I have a hard time believing this is desirable behavior for tags. So, I'll go with "support" for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag still exists, because [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683906/bit-error-probability-for-8psk?noredirect=1) still exists here, as a "migration stub". Such stubs are deleted from the origin site in 30 days. After that, the tag will be gone too.

A moderator could speed up the process by retagging or deleting the stub, although there doesn't seem to be much need.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I figured it wasn't something *too* out of the ordinary, but I hadn't encountered it and searches didn't turn up anything exactly relevant.